# Make Windows PC blur my screen instead of showing the lock screen image when I lock it

Tags: windows, windows-10, lock-screen, lock

Is it possible to make my Windows 10 PC show whatever is shown on my screen blurred at the lock screen?

Comment: hm, but unless something nonlinear or noisy happens, a blurred screen can [relatively trivially be deconvolved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95171) to show nearly the same resolution as the unblurred version; you can get a lot better if you actually know that the thing you're looking for in the deblurred image is e.g. text of a relatively small range of possible sizes; you'd hence lose the privacy effect of a lock screen. Is this acceptable to your use case?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. Not out of the box.

The following is a *theory* I have.. prolly would work.

If you are a badass, you might be able to trick out "[Windows Spotlight](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/windows-spotlight)" to showing whatever images you want.  This would require you using GPEdit to assign a specific picture to the lock screen, writing a "lock screen" trigger that generated a screenshot, blurring it, and assigning it to the picture you defined using group policy.  Specifics for assigning a specific picture can be found in the link.

Again, I have not tested this theory but I bet it could work.  Not worth the effort if you ask me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants to actually blur the screen realtime and keep updates in place which means a custom lockscreen app.

Comment: @LpChip No I don't want that

Comment: @LPChip .. you are ***super smart***.  I always appreciate your feedback.  A custom lockscreen app is not an easy thing to write.. sure, easier than the old GINA stuff.. but very difficult at best as the account driving the lock screen is not the current user.  This really makes things difficult.

Comment: Thank you. :) In this case, OP confirmed they did not want a realtime lockscreen, so your answer could work. The activation part is going to be harder though. You can't lock the screen and use TaskScheduler's on lock feature. So, probably a custom activation sequence that creates the screenshot, performs blur on it, set it as lockscreen image and then perform the lock. A custom lock screen app could also still work, but is obviously less secure. Then again, the entire idea behind this is less secure.